# A Clear Map of Lake Makgadikgadi

Tags: worldbuilding-process, map-making, worldbuilding-resources

In prehistoric times, the Makgadikgadi pans were part of the largest lake Africa has ever seen. Covering 250,000 square kilometers (96,500 square miles), it was far larger than present-day Lake Victoria.

For whatever reason, Google could not give me a clear, outlined map of the supposed shape, size, location and extent of this ancient megalake, let alone one to Magic Wand on Photoshop.

Could any of you help me out on this one?

Comment: not a answer that gives a map but "At its largest it probably stretched as far as Lake Ngami in the west, what is now Chobe in the north, and beyond Nata to the edge of present-day Zimbabwe in the east." and " The great Magwikwe Sand Ridge that you cross as you drive between Savuti and North Gate, probably defined one of its northwestern shorelines. Similarly, another is thought to have been the less obvious Gidikwe Sand Ridge, which lies just to the west of the western border of the present Makgadikgadi National Park"...http://www.botswana-travel-guide.com/bradt_guide.asp?bradt=1171

Answer (score 1):

http://en-zw.topographic-map.com/places/Makgadikgadi-Pan-2704742/

I figured a topographical map of the area would show low lying areas which likely were once full of water.  Linked is the best I found.  Which, fortuitously, shows the low elevation areas surrounding the current pan and water in light blue!   These ancient lakes like most lakes probably had different shapes over time but I think the low elevation demarcates the maximum extent.

Google maps shows you something similar (and I think this site jumps off of google maps with their colorization).  Irritatingly I could not figure out how to turn off the green square representing the park, which obscures the underlying (subtle) color changes representing elevation.

Comment: So that's it?  That's all the lake ever was?  Because I've read that "Today the only remains of Lake Makgadikgadi are the Okavango Delta, the Nxai Pan, Lake Ngami, Lake Xau, the Mababe Depression, and the two main Makgadikgadi pans of Sua and Nwetwe."

Comment: That blue is 915 meters.  If everything < 1000 meters was underwater that would include the Okovango delta.  I was dissatisfied with how the linked map depicted Okovango when I zoomed out.  I found this one.  Maybe 1000 and lower is the lake?  http://www.botswanatourism.us/images/topography_big.jpg

Comment: JohnWDailey I am hoping you will edit this to undo the close votes.  Your question reminded me of Lovecraft's Shadow out of Time which mentions a "general of the great-headed brown people who held South Africa in B.C. 50,000".  I think about that general sometimes and wonder what her world was like.